# Hardware thread vs soft threads?

Tags: multithreading, hardware

I have read that in a multi core processor each core contains 2 hardware threads for example in dual core processor 4 hardware threads are running. Now if i create 2 threads in java are those threads going to map with 2 hardware threads or those 2 java threads are executed by single hardware thread of a particular core ?

Comment: The OS is responsible for distributing threads across processors; if your threads are doing a lot of work, the OS will probably put them on different CPUs.

Comment: Similar q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508301/on-which-operationg-system-is-threaded-programming-sufficient-to-utilize-multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is dependent on a lot of things, however the 2 hardware threads per core you are referring to is the Intel HyperThreading technology.  This technology enables the CPU to have two Thread Context's in memory and be executing simultaneously, sharing execution resources.

What threads run where is OS implemention dependent and mostly resolved by the Thread Scheduler algorithm of your OS.

Comment: But is it these software threads and java threads and hardware threads are dependent or indipendent ? because java thredas are created inside a process called jvm...

Comment: This description of Intel's Hyper-threading is not accurate.  *Some* resources are alternately provided to one or the other thread, but *execution units are shared* and both threads may be getting actual work done at the same time.  Of course there is least contention for resources when one thread is stalled.  [More here (PDF)](http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2002/volume06issue01/vol6iss1_hyper_threading_technology.pdf).